# Plot table and display Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to display my Pandas dataframe on screen in a tabular format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'apples': 10, 'bananas': 15, 'pears': 5}, [0])
```

I'm not sure how to do so. I know that pd.DataFrame.plot() has some options to display a table, but only along with the graph. I just want to display the table (i.e. dataframe) on screen. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's a screenshot of creating a table using pandas plot function. I only want the bottom table portion however, not the graph. I also want a popup of the table figure.

[image: plotting tables]

**EDIT 2:**

I managed to display my dataframe on the figure with the following:

```
plt.figure()
y = [0]
plt.table(cellText=[10, 15, 5], rowLabels=[0], columnLabels=['apple', 'bananas', 'pears'], loc='center')
plt.axis('off')
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

This will display just the table without any of the axes. I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, so any suggestions would be appreciated. Also, is there a way to add a title to this table? The only way I know would be to use plt.text and place the text (title of the table) within the figure, but then I would have to keep the axes...Any ideas?

Comment: What Python GUI are you using? If it's IPython it should display nicely...

Comment: yup, even in python repl, typing df<enter> or print(df) prints nicely.

Comment: Added a screenshot of what I want to my question

Comment: By the way I'm using PyDev within Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line 2-4 hide the graph above,but somehow the graph still preserve some space for the figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) 
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
    colWidths = [0.5]*len(col_labels),
    rowLabels=row_labels, colLabels=col_labels,
    cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center')

plt.show()
```