# Python pandas summary table plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Really can't get to grips with how to plot a summary table of a pandas df. I'm sure this is not a case for a pivot table, or maybe a transposed method of displaying the data. Best I could find was : [Plot table and display Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773991/plot-table-and-display-pandas-dataframe) 
My code attempts are just not getting there:

```
dc = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],'B' : [4, 3, 2, 1],'C' : [4, 3, 2, 1]})
data = dc['A'],dc['B'],dc['C']

ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) 
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
cols=["A", "B", "C"]
row_labels=[0]
the_table = plt.table(cellText=data,colWidths = [0.5]*len(cols),rowLabels=row_labels, colLabels=cols,cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center')
plt.show()
```

All I would like to do, is produce a table plot, with A B C in the first column, and the total and mean in the rows next to them (see below). Any help or guidance would be great...feeling really stupid... (excuse the code example, it doesn't yet have the total and mean yet included...)

```
   Total   Mean
A     x      x
B     x      x
C     x      x
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dc = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],'B' : [4, 3, 2, 1],'C' : [3, 4, 2, 2]})

plt.plot(dc)
plt.legend(dc.columns)
dcsummary = pd.DataFrame([dc.mean(), dc.sum()],index=['Mean','Total'])

plt.table(cellText=dcsummary.values,colWidths = [0.25]*len(dc.columns),
          rowLabels=dcsummary.index,
          colLabels=dcsummary.columns,
          cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
          loc='top')
fig = plt.gcf()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the help cphlewis, this was great! To end it off for anyone else wanting a similar table plot: using cphlewis answer and by switching of the axis visible settings to False, and swapping the column and index, a table as in my question is plotted with no line graph.

Answer (score 3):

Does the `dataFrame.describe()` function helps you?
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

Sorry, not enough points for comments.